# How to split a JSON document in Mongo

Tags: json, mongodb

I have documents of the following format:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58af1ee3f78a9945bd9fc94d"),
"rounds" : {
    "matches" : {
        "team1" : {
            "name" : "Manchester United",
            "score1" : 1
        },
        "team2" : {
            "name" : "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "score2" : 0
        }
    }
}}
```

And I would like to get somenthing like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("SomeID"),
"rounds" : {
    "matches" : {
        "team1" : {
            "name" : "Manchester United",
            "score1" : 1
        }
    }
}
```

}

and

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("SomeID"),
"rounds" : {
    "matches" : {
         "team2" : {
            "name" : "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "score2" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

}

I'm looking for something like unwind but unwind is applied only on arrays. How can I transform matches into an array of JSON? Any other ideas to achieved the desired result are welcome

Comment: Why are you not maintaining the matches as arrays? Any specific reason?

Comment: Matches is a nested field, not an array. If I could convert matches to an array, I would use unwind. That's the only idea I had but I don't know how to do that

Comment: Maybe try using [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a mapreduce function, with just a map function?  I don't really know your use case but if you are just returning one document at a time it might be best to do the refactoring after mongo returns the results.

```
db.somcollection.mapReduce(
function(){
    var matcharray = [];
    for (var match in this.rounds.matches) {
        if (this.rounds.matches.hasOwnProperty(match)) {
          matcharray.push({team:match,other:this.rounds.matches[match]});
        }
    }
    emit('matches',matcharray);

},
function(key,values){   
    return ( values );
},
{
    query:{"_id" : ObjectId("58af1ee3f78a9945bd9fc94d")},
    out: "somename"
}).find()
```

This results in the following, which is at least an array but not quite what you wanted using key/value pairs for everything.

```
{
"_id" : "matches",
"value" : [ 
    {
        "team" : "team1",
        "other" : {
            "name" : "Manchester United",
            "score1" : 1
        }
    }, 
    {
        "team" : "team2",
        "other" : {
            "name" : "Tottenham Hotspur",
            "score2" : 0
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't responded earlier. Thanks for the answer, it helped a lot :)